# nM or μM, which is more concentrated?

Tags: units

A study found that a particular herb fueled cancer at nM concentrations but actually inhibited cancer in μM concentrations. Which is the higher concentration, nM or μM?

Answer (score 3):

Although molar is the standardised SI unit for concentration, metric prefixes also exist in order to make the numbers more manageable (i.e. to allow small fractions of units to be discussed easily).

The Wikipedia page for molar concentration gives a table of commonly used prefixes, you can clearly see that a micromolar solution is 1000 times more concentrated than a nanomolar solution (which itself is 1000 times more concentrated than a picomolar solution).

> [image]
>
> **Source:** Wikipedia

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much! I could not understand without your interpretation of the concentration.